# Using MIN on numbers that are text data types?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I realize this is bad table design (not mine).

Say one wants to use MIN(Biweekly_High_Rate) excluding 0.00

```
+--------------------+
| Biweekly_High_Rate |
+--------------------+
| $0.00              |
| $15.00             |
| $25.00             |
| $50.00             |
| $100.00            |
| $100.00            |
| $200.00            |
| $500.00            |
| $0.00              |
| $10630.00          |
| $9175.00           |
| $4142.00           |
| $5242.00           |
| $3293.00           |
| $4496.00           |
| $4676.00           |
| $4762.00           |
| $11255.00          |
| $10376.00          |
| $9096.00           |
| $9456.00           |
| $9641.00           |
| $7392.00           |
| $7687.00           |
| $7835.00           |
+--------------------+
```

running

```
Select min(Biweekly_high_Rate)
From salary_range_by_job_classification
Where (biweekly_high_Rate != "$0.00");
```

returns

```
+-------------------------+
| min(Biweekly_high_Rate) |
+-------------------------+
| $100.00                 |
+-------------------------+
```

Where it should be $15.00

Now I realize why this is happening.
The question is How to execute a query to return $15.00?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some of them have numeric sensitive collations.)

Comment: Not entirely sure... it's some interactive course online. lets just say its SQLite

Comment: You have to extract the number part from the string.

Comment: unfortunately they haven't taught that yet. I'll try and google it

Answer (score 3):

You can use combination of two functions, trim the dollar sign first, and then convert it the remaining part to a number :

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(LTRIM(Biweekly_high_Rate,'$') AS DECIMAL)) 
  FROM t
 WHERE CAST(LTRIM(Biweekly_high_Rate,'$') AS DECIMAL)!=0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dc09be5ac192b4169c47aef8f79cca99)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

One method is to order by the length and then the value -- and then limit the value to one row:

```
Select Biweekly_high_Rate
From salary_range_by_job_classification
Where biweekly_high_Rate <> '$0.00'
order by length(Biweekly_high_Rate) asc, Biweekly_high_Rate asc
limit 1;
```

This works because the strings have the same format -- a leading `'$'` and two decimal places.

Note:  That some databases use `len()` and some use `length()` for string length.

Comment: this is a nice trick, and I appreciate the response. I'm just confused why the course says it started the query for me using MIN(Biweekly_high_Rate) and I'm supposed to filter it when it's so difficult to do so it's suppose to be a fundamentals lecture. Either it was a bad question design or there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ...

```
WITH
-- your input ...
salary_range_by_job_classification(biweekly_high_rate) as (
          SELECT '$0.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$15.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$25.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$50.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$100.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$100.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$200.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$500.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$0.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$10630.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$9175.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$4142.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$5242.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$3293.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$4496.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$4676.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$4762.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$11255.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$10376.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$9096.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$9456.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$9641.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$7392.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$7687.00'
UNION ALL SELECT '$7835.00'
)
SELECT
  -- the first character is the dollar sign. 
  -- the rest is a numeric literal. Cast that as a DECIMAL(9,2).
  -- so start from the second character of the string, using SUBSTR().
  -- then use the same cast and filter out zeroes.
  MIN(CAST(SUBSTR(biweekly_high_rate,2) AS DECIMAL(9,2))) AS minrate
FROM salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE CAST(SUBSTR(biweekly_high_rate,2) AS DECIMAL(9,2)) > 0
;
-- out  minrate 
-- out ---------
-- out    15.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    Select * from table where 
    Biweekly_high_Rate not like '$0.0%'
    order by 
   substr(2,Biweekly_high_Rate, 
    length(Biweekly_high_Rate)) 
     Limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the numeric part of the value to a number by simply adding `0`, use `MIN()` to get its minimum and use the function `printf()` to reformat it:

```
select printf('$%.2f', min(substr(Biweekly_High_Rate, 2) + 0)) min_rate
from salary_range_by_job_classification
where Biweekly_High_Rate <> '$0.00'
```

Or with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
select distinct first_value(Biweekly_High_Rate) over (order by substr(Biweekly_High_Rate, 2) + 0) min_rate
from salary_range_by_job_classification
where Biweekly_High_Rate <> '$0.00'
```

Or sort by the numeric part and get the 1st row:

```
select Biweekly_High_Rate min_rate
from salary_range_by_job_classification
where Biweekly_High_Rate <> '$0.00' 
order by substr(Biweekly_High_Rate, 2) + 0 limit 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2dcc82fac060fb0a9bd08ce60387153d).
Results:

```
> | min_rate |
> | :------- |
> | $15.00   |
```